# eval two codes in same context in javascript

Tags: javascript, eval

My goal is to allow the user to enter lines of code at different moments and have them add up in the same context, but I want to run them in a new context to prevent `this` from being `window`.

I tried this but I see the changes made to the context aren't kept:

```
var context = {};
var run = new Function("console.log(this === context);var a = 3");
run.call(context); // outputs 'true'
var run = new Function("console.log(a)");
run.call(context); // fails with 'a is not defined', I hoped it would write '3'
```

Is there some way I can achieve this?

Comment: why don't you want _this_ to be window?

Comment: yikes, don't use `new Function`.  there's very rarely any good reason for that.

Comment: var run = new Function("with(this){console.log(a)}"); would work how you want... using with and eval at once will be slow, but for math i doubt it matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scope and context are completely different things, and `eval` doesn't enter into it. Your code is identical to

```
var run = function () { console.log(this === context);var a = 3);
```

There is no way to access `a` outside the function. The scope where `a` is declared isn't the calling scope, it's the functions *own* scope, and as written `a` has nothing to do with either `this` or `context`.

If you want two functions to share context, you need to use `this.a = 3`, not `var a = 3`.